# git merge causing conflicts that need to be fixed manually?

Tags: git

I think I understand git sometimes and then it does something weird...

I created a branch2 for making some edit, was satisfied, committed everything on my branch2. I then switched to master and did...

```
git merge branch2
```

Basically, this just caused a whole load of conflicts which was pretty much everything I just edited in the branch2, and I had to go through and fix them all. How can I avoid this? Is this the proper behavior? Should I be using a different command?

EDIT ADDING GIT LOG STUFF:

```
*   206c48b (HEAD, master, forum-header) Merge branch 'spirit'
|\  
| * 1ac143b Deleted a lot of djangobb stuff, got spirit working, working on getting everything together
* | f3b08b7 Committing before starting a new spirit branch
|/
```

Comment: Show us where you branched from initially (`git log --graph --oneline --decorate --boundary master...branch2` for instance; note the 3 dots here) and a sample of some of the conflicts.

Comment: @torek, added to post

Comment: OK, still could use a sample of conflicts though.  I can't tell if there were "real" conflicts or some issue with EOL (cr-lf vs newline), for instance...

Comment: ok I am not used to doing anything unusual in git, so I am not sure how to go about retrieving those conflicts after I have already fixed them. If I am not mistaken I believe I started the branch with uncommitted changes on master and then committed them on the f3b08b7 commit and then made more changes on the branch2. Would that cause conflicts?

Comment: You could re-create them (re-attempt the merge, perhaps on an anonymous branch / detached HEAD; it's not hard to do, but it's confusing).  Anyway just as a general rule, a conflict occurs when git sees the *same part* of some file changed on both sides.  For instance if in `f3b0b87` you changed file `README` to remove the first line, and in `1ac143b` you changed `README` to fix the spelling of a word in the first line, git can't combine those changes and gives you a conflict instead.

Comment: ok that is definitely what happened then. I think commits should always be made before branching/merging, without exception, right? Sometimes I just forget to do it

Comment: It's generally wise to commit often, yes. :-)